# Can tab be remapped in nvi?

Tags: vi

I want to map tab in [nvi(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nvi&sektion=1). When I try to map a literal tab by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it does not get rendered as `^I` and `nvi(1)` shows "Usage: map[!] [keys replace]". Can tab be remapped in nvi?

Answer (score 0):

To map tab, you have to use ^V twice e.g. type ":map " then <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.